# Concatenate multiple unequal dataframes on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 7 dataframes (df_1, df_2, df_3,..., df_7) all with the same columns but **different lengths** but sometimes have the **same values**.

I'd like to concatenate all 7 dataframes under the **conditions** that:

```
if df_n.iloc[row_i] != df_n+1.iloc[row_i] and df_n.iloc[row_i][0] < df_n+1.iloc[row_i][0]:

      pd.concat([df_n.iloc[row_i], df_n+1.iloc[row_i], df_n+2.iloc[row_i],
      ...., df_n+6.iloc[row_i]])
```

Where `df_n.iloc[row_i]` is the ith row of the nth dataframe and `df_n.iloc[row_i][0]` is the first column of the ith row.

For example if we only had 2 dataframes and that `len(df_1)` < `len(df_2)` and if we used the **conditions above** the **input** would be:

```
df_1                                    df_2

index    0      1       2               index    0        1       2
0        12.12  11.0    31              0        12.2     12.6    30
1        12.3   12.1    33              1        12.3     12.1    33
2        10     9.1     33              2        13       12.1    23
3        16     12.1    33              3        13.1     12.1    27
                                        4        14.4     13.1    27
                                        5        15.2     13.2    28
```

And the **output** would be:

```
conditions -> pd.concat([df_1, df_2]):

index    0      1       2      3      4      5     
0        12.12  11.0    31     12.2   12.6   30
2        10     9.1     33     13     12.1   23
4        nan                   14.4   13.1   27
5        nan                   15.2   13.2   28
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC `concat` first , the `groupby` by columns get the different , and we just implement your condition

```
s=pd.concat([df1,df2],1)
s1=s.groupby(level=0,axis=1).apply(lambda x : x.iloc[:,0]-x.iloc[:,1])
yourdf=s[s1.ne(0).any(1)&s1.iloc[:,0].lt(0)|s1.iloc[:,0].isnull()]
Out[487]: 
           0     1     2     0     1   2
index                                   
0      12.12  11.0  31.0  12.2  12.6  30
2      10.00   9.1  33.0  13.0  12.1  23
4        NaN   NaN   NaN  14.4  13.1  27
5        NaN   NaN   NaN  15.2  13.2  28
```